# is it file or directory in ftp while using curl CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY

Tags: c, curl

I have function, that prints out list of files on ftp server. But I would like to know is it directory or file. How to solve this problem?

```
struct FtpFile {
  const char *filename;
  FILE *stream;
};

static size_t my_fwrite(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{


  struct FtpFile *out=(struct FtpFile *)stream;
char *p =buffer;
printf(p);
  if(out && !out->stream) {
    /* open file for writing */
    out->stream=fopen(out->filename, "wb");
    if(!out->stream)
      return -1; /* failure, can't open file to write */
  }
  return fwrite(buffer, size, nmemb, out->stream);
}

bool GetFilesList()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;


    struct FtpFile ftpfile={"tmp.txt", /* name to store the file as if succesful */ NULL };




    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://sample.com/updFile1.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ftpfile);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_fwrite);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }



    if(CURLE_OK != res)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: In C, `struct FtpFile *out=(struct FtpFile *)stream;` should be `struct FtpFile *out = stream;`.

Comment: Is that mistake? So, why it compiles then?

Comment: @userXXX It is a mistake, but not a syntax error (it's just dangerous and not idiomatic).